# Efficient way to get Max number from CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have large number of documents (~2 million). I have to query for highest `num` for a given dictionary Key.

Expected output from below two documents would be `'3'` for given key `'85642768'`.

Doc1:

```
{
    "id": "fb41ecd9-2761-41f4-87ca-aa4bf59f9d83",
    "Key": "Key123",
    "Dict": {
        "85642766": {
            "num": 1,
            "str": "str1"
        },
        "85642767": {
            "num": 1,
            "str": "str2"
        },
        "85642768": {
            "num": 2,
            "str": "str3"
        }
    }
}
```

Doc2:

```
{
    "id": "821cf017-421a-422a-b082-45e77228dca3",
    "Key": "Key456",
    "Dict": {
        "85642766": {
            "num": 1,
            "str": "str1"
        },
        "85642767": {
            "num": 2,
            "str": "str2"
        },
        "85642768": {
            "num": 3,
            "str": "str3"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I have 250K unique documents. I am downloading list of documents based on list of `Key` in batches of 8000. It takes 14 mins with 10000 RUs in same location.

I have an index based on `Key` also. Is there any better way to reduce search time?

Comment: CosmosDB is a database. Instead of downloading all documents and processing them locally, you send it a query to produce the result for you. 250K is almost no data at all -  a small SQL Server database on a laptop could handle GBs of data.

Comment: CosmosDB [allows querying using SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-query-sql-api), including [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-group-by) and aggregate functions. Have you tried that?

Comment: The code you have written would be useful, but I agree with others, it sounds like you are downloading all the data to process it locally, rather than asking the server to produce the answer.

Comment: Aside from what others have stated (that you shouldn't be downloading an entire collection to do local searching and aggregating): you should reconsider your data model: your `Dict` subdocument is using a key's value as its name, meaning there is no practical way to search for an arbitrary key.

Answer (score 0):

As comment above says,you can use sql do this thing.

Please try something like this sql:

`SELECT value max(c.Dict["85642768"].num) from c`

Hope this can help you.